# Why does getBackStackEntryCount() always return 0?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

Do i understand correctly that `getBackStackEntryCount()` returns a number of transactions which have been commited ? If it's so why does the following code return 0 ?

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
Fragment fragment = new CrimeFragment();
fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();
Log.d(MAIN_ACTIVITY_LOG_TAG,Integer.toString(fm.getBackStackEntryCount()));
```

I want to note:

1. I tried to use `commitNow()` insted of the `commit()`
2. I tried to use `fm.executePendingTransactions();` after the `commit()` and before `getBackStackEntryCount()`
3. I tried to use `getBackStackEntryCount()` in `onResume()`
4. I use androidx `FragmentManager`. This is my imports:

```
package com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
```

Comment: Why would `getBackStackCount()` increase if you don't call `addToBackStack()`?

Comment: Oh, i thought a transaction is added to back stack automatically after commiting :)